# Use Resources in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-resources

I am using a `ViewPager` in my app, based on a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

I have hundreds of `Fragments` that are loaded and displayed dynamically in this `ViewPager`, all this is working well but I sometimes get null pointers when trying to access resources using:

```
getResources().getString(R.id.example);
```

What is the best way to access `Resources` in `Fragments`? Would it be a good idea to create a global variable and initialize it (maybe in `onActivityCreated()`)?

I am also concerned about the memory itself, as I am not sure which one is the heaviest between using a global variable on every fragment or directly accessing the resources from the `Activity` (getResources()).

Comment: first of all if you want to access `String` then used  `getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.example);` in your  `Fragment ` and no need to defined it Globally

Comment: I am using this, but I am getting random null pointers when the `Activity` is not ready yet. It seems impossible to use getResources() on functions like `onCreate` or `onCreateView` because the Activity is not necessarily created before the fragment ...

Comment: try putting your code under `onAttach() Fragment` take some time to attach to `Activity`. Till this happens, sometimes we get `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2):

Make this a global variable

```
private View view;
```

and then on onCreateView(), add this line

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
```

and now you can access the resources

```
view.getResources().getString(R.string.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
getActivity().getResources().getString(R.id.example);
```

Comment: I am using this currently but I am not sure it is necessarily the best way. I have a lot of strings to retrieve from the `Resources` and so I have to do dozens of call to the `Activity`. Those calls sometimes give null pointers on configuration changes like screen rotations.